# Are there any way to get (75V 1A) output from 78V input

Tags: current-source

Is there any way to get 75 V 1 A output from 78 V input?

I found the [TL783](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl783.pdf) high voltage adjustable regulator. But this can supply only 700mA output current.

I had forgot to tell the details.

Main purpose of this power supply is high precision sensor circuit.

Previously, when required 5V : Step down to 8v with a switching regulator first, then step down to 5v with linear regulator.
It is for the sake of stability of the power supply voltage.

When required 12V : Step down to 15V with a switching regulator first, then step down to 12V with linear regulator.

When required 24V : Step down to 27V with a switching regulator first, then step down to 24V with linear regulator.

This time required 75V and step down to 78v with a switching regulator first, then step down to 75V. I've tried...

This way I have wrong?

Comment: If the 78v is already regulated, you can drop this down to near 75v using four diodes in series: 4*0.7(Vf) = 2.8v, so you would end up with 75.2v

Answer (score 4):

3V error at 75 is only 4%. Most regulators won't do much better than that. Are you sure you really need your 75V more than 4% accurate?

And how accurate is your 78V? If it drops by a few % it can get below the 75V mark, and your regulator will have to operate in an 'interesting' mode.

The TL783 you found is a variation of the LM317. Most plain LM317's can handle 1.5A, but be sure to provide cooling (even at 3V drop 1A means 3W, which is more than a bare TO220 can handle).

Note that an LM317 can handle only a limited voltage (typically 35 or 40V), but that is the voltage difference *between input and output*. In normal operation the LM317 never 'sees' the ground voltage, so it happily drops 78 V to 75V (3V is the minimum drop for an LM317). BUT it would have a problem when you ever short the output to ground: then it would suddenly see a 78V drop and it would probably die. (Note that with an 78V drop the power dissipation with a shorted output would be very large.)

Comment: The LM317 can handle only up to 37V. And even the HV version of it goes up to only 60V.

Comment: sir why can't we use simple diode assembly or rubber diode with a power transistor here?

Comment: What's a rubber diode??? (zener?) - Note that my mian point is that the OP probably does not need any circuit at all.

Comment: I stand corrected :) There is even an [AppNote](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva583/snva583.pdf) by TI which goes up to 160V (and adds protection against shorting the output).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you ought to consider a buck-boost regulator like this device: -

[image]

It's not a "beginners project" but it will do exactly what you want I believe and work with voltage supplies well below your 75V output voltage level. Top input voltage is limited to 80V.

Comment: The 78V the OP has as input is dangerously close to the 80V this chip can handle - just a 2% margin. It might be better to use e.g. an [LTC3810](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC3810) which handles 100V (and is easier to use too). There are similar parts from TI, but it will be hard to a linear regulator at these voltages and current.

Comment: @hli - maybe make an answer with this part offered. I'm not sure how close it can get the output to the input rail - this might be a problem - that's why I went for buck-boost.

Comment: Sorry, I had forgot to tell the details. I want to step down with linear regulator for stability of the power supply voltage. So I can't select this.

Answer (score -1):

Check IT :
     [image]

I am using this method to make certain power supplies. Make Higher Voltage Around 5 To 10 Volt ... And Then ... Make My Voltage By Another Roegulaor ... This Way Limit My Accuracy By Last Regulator ... For Example If I Need 75V ... I Make 80V And Make My Voltage By 7805 ... This Way Limit My Accuracy To 5* ( Accuracy Of Regulator )

Comment: This is just @Wouter van Ooijen's answer.

Comment: I'll try this. Do you have any notes?